# How to open links in a new tab?

Tags: browser, web, browser-tabs

I am used to open links in a new tab by clicking scroll on my mouse. Starting from middle 2020 more and more websites are blocking this: when I click scroll wheel on something, I get a circle with arrows, when I click with right button - there is no "Open in a new tab". Only left button click works, but this is extremely unconvenient when I need to check multiple search results or open multiple menu items.

How do I fix this? I prefer Chrome, but will switch to anything that works.

EDIT: On Reddit: try to scrollclick the word "Posted" in any post.
Or try to do the same as on image below, open https://shop.silpo.ua, click "Всі товари" and then try to open anything in a new tab.

[image]

Comment: Middle click definitely works as expected in both Firefox and Edge for me. Have you tried disabling all your add-ons to see if it is being caught  by one of them?

Comment: Seems like you have switched mouse software. The same happens to me - when my mouse software is not running, the Windows generic mouse driver generates a circle with arrow for the scroll button.

Comment: @Mokubai, go to Reddit, try to scrollclick the word "Posted" in ANY post on the main page (or rightclick it, there will be no "Open in a new tab").

Comment: @harrymc, I have a generic mouse, this is definitely something with websites blocking opening in a new tab.

Comment: @real_sm the word "posted" is not a link, the username and time next to it are links but "posted" is not. Other than that a website may have elements that are not clickable.

Comment: The reason "posted" works for left mouse button is because a clickable area has been set up by javascript but is not a real link.

Comment: @Mokubai, OK, so now I think the question is: how do I open such clickable areas in a new tab?

Comment: @real_sm find an area that is a proper link. Either the "x hours ago", or "576 comments" or so on

Comment: @Mokubai. OK, Reddit fixed. How do I do that on https://shop.silpo.ua (see original post)?